# Sending events to 3rd party domains with Google Analytics Universal

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We provide an iframe-based embeddable widget to our clients and want to be able to send their Google Analytics account events based on what is happening inside our iframe. We used to be able to do this using the old ga.js with the following code:

```
_gaq.push(['NAMESPACE._setAccount', CUSTOMER_GA_ACCOUNT_ID]);
_gaq.push(['NAMESPACE._setDomainName', CUSTOMER_DOMAIN]);
_gaq.push(['NAMESPACE._trackEvent',"category", "event", "label"]);
```

This code would be fired inside our iframe, but would result in an event being pushed to the customer's google analytics account, letting them have some insight into customer behavior inside our embeddable widget. The NAMESPACE in front of the actions would keep these events separate from our GA stuff, and would prevent our GA stuff from going to their GA account. They would provide us with their Google Analytics account ID when they wanted to enable this feature.

**Is there a way to do something similar with the new Universal Analytics API?**

I don't seem to see a similar way to namespace actions and the cross-domain tracking documentation doesn't indicate how to send events/pageviews to two domains/GA accounts (ie we want to track pageviews on our GA account, and send the events to our customer's GA account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest going the roundabout way - set a pixel in your widget and make the actual endpoint for that pixel a script on your server that sends the data via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to your clients analytics account.